# Can I represent an Inertia Tensor with a Quaternion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

We can store three-dimensional rotations in 3x3 matrices, and in quaternions. since we usually store angular Momentum within a 3x3 matrix, would it be possible to use a quaternion to store/repersent the same values?

Comment: How do you propose to store 6 real numbers (principal moments + orientation *or* unique components of general $I_{ab}$) in a quaternion with 4 real entries? Rotations are different because you need only specify three real numbers (cf. the axis-angle representation), so they fit comfortably in a quaternion.

Comment: You can transform the Inertia Tensor from body frame B to intertial frame  O ,$I_O= RI_{B}R^{T}$ where the transformation matrix R is function of the quaternion